# If you roll a fair six sided die three times, what's the probability that you get the same number three times

Tags: probability

I got quite confused after looking at another example of this kind on stack exchange.

So would the answer for that simply be 1/6 * 1/6 * 1/6 *6

And if we said we wanted 5 in all three cases than would it simply be 
 1/6 * 1/6 * 1/6

Comment: Both calculations are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a specific number to appear three times in a row, you want it to appear on first, second and third roll. Which leads to $\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}$. If, however, you just want ANY number to appear three times in a row, then first $\frac{1}{6}$ disappears from previous formula. Why?

It is because it does not really matter, what you roll first. You just want second and third roll to be the same as the first one. Hence first throw is not really important, since it only indicates which number has to be rolled twice from this moment. It's not a formal proof, but I guess you needed the simple reasoning behind the whole idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot that did clarify it for me.

Answer (score 0):

If each roll is independent of each other (which from your description it sounds like it is), then the probability of rolling the number-5 3 times <5,5,5> is 
$$
\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}= \frac{1}{216}
$$

Note that any other permutations also has this probability. For example, <1,2,1> or <5,6,2>.
This is because each roll is independent of the previous roll.